# Scaling out SignalR to multiple WebApp and WebJob instances

Tags: azure, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-backplane

I have a .NET web application that is deployed as a multi-instance Azure Web App. This web application makes use of SignalR to broadcast messages to connected clients. I'm scaling out using a Service Bus backplane, and this works great.

I also have a continuous WebJob that monitors a Service Bus queue, does some intensive processing, and as part of that processing needs to send out a broadcast message to SignalR clients.

It seems that there are two ways I can go with this:

1. Treat the WebJob as a SignalR client by connecting with my SignalR Hub running on the Web App using a HubConnection and an IHubProxy. This seems to work well, and is what I'm currently doing.
2. Somehow treat the WebJob as another Hub, and add it to the Service Bus backplane. I am not sure how I'd do this. I would then just broadcast messages using an IHubContext that I get from the SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.

My questions are:

1. Is one way of doing this substantially better than another?
2. If option #2 is better, can someone post a link to how I'd go about doing this? It seems that most tutorials are in regards to a multi-instance scale-out using either SQL Server, Service Bus Topics, or Redis as the backplane.